# HTML error message recurs too quickly

Tags: javascript, dhtml, user-experience

From the submit button's onClick, I am displaying a validation error in a DIV with:

```
msgStr = validate(...);
document.getElementById("msgArea").innerHTML = msgStr;
```

But if the user clicks submit again (possibly changing the data but getting the same validation error), there is no feedback to them that the submit actually did anything.  The page sits there "frozen" (to the user).

I tried to clear the area before calling validation with:

```
document.getElementById("msgArea").innerHTML = '';
msgStr = validate();
document.getElementById("msgArea").innerHTML = msgStr;
```

but this doesn't show any effect.  I assume that either the browser doesn't have time to update the rendering before the same msgStr is set, or it happens so quickly that the user doesn't see the "flash".

Any suggestions on how to provide feedback in this case?

Comment: How are you getting the value for the validation ?

Comment: The validate() function simply validates that certain form fields have the appropriate format (e.g. email address contains "@", phone number matches ###-###-####, name is not empty, etc.).  So validate() simply returns a (possibly empty) string with concatenated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that you don't see it change because the flash is too fast. If you're using a javascript library (jquery, yui, etc...), you can use a fade in function to make it more noticeable. If not, you can use a series of timers and style changes to make the change more noticeable. Here's a fiddle that demonstrates how to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/cbargren/S6ZjC/

Comment: Ah, cool idea and thanks for the sample.  I'll see if I can work something like this in.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like JavaScript might be dying somewhere.

Open you page in Google Chrome and go to "tools > JavaScript Console."

If it is breaking you will see red error messages. From there you have a better chance at knowing what the problem is. If you are still stumped tell us the errors you are getting along with any additional useful code.

Comment: No, it is not that JS is dying.  There are no error messages and I can step through the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, the problem is due to the idea that your steps are sequential but in actual fact occur near instantaneous from a user's perspective.

I'd be looking to apply an "updated" state to the form (eg: a class) which changes in some small way the validation message. That way, upon validation the "udpated" state is removed (that is, the data is once again "stale") until such time as the user changes something again. This works better with focus and/or alterations to the data (so you need to hold the content until an update to a field occurs).